# Get the role(s) of a member in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that shows the roles of the mentions user.
This command is a test command which I am going to implement into my mute command. (the command will remove the member's current role and add the mute role)

This is what I have:

```
@client.command()
async def roles(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  roles = member.roles
  role_names = [role.name for role in roles]
  await ctx.send(role_names)
```

The command works fine, but the output isn't quite what I expected.

Output:

```
['@everyone', 'Member']
```

It correctly displays the 2 roles mentioned by the user, but it isn't formatted in the specific way I want.

I want the output to simply be "Member" or whatever other roles the mentioned member has besides @everyone. basically, I want to remove the square brackets and "@everyone" from the output, leaving only the role name.

Hopefully, somebody can help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your problem you just have to format the information from `role_names` in string form and remove the `'@everyone'`. You can use a list comprehension and the join() method .
Here would be the amended code:

```
@client.command()
async def roles(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  roles = member.roles
  role_names = ' '.join([role.name for role in roles if role.name != '@everyone'])
  await ctx.send(role_names)
```